# Encrypt String Roku BrightScript

Tags: roku, brightscript

Im newbie in BrightScript,

I would like to know how to encrypt the string.
can you give me an example?

This is my code

```
  esn = m.constants.deviceSerialID
```

How to encrypt the result of this?

i got research but i don't know how to use and how to put the code

```html
https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifEVPCipher
```

Comment: I looked into this but was not able to figure it out from the roku docs; did you try the dev forum? https://forums.roku.com/viewforum.php?f=34

Comment: yes, we talk the roku developers, actually the encryption are not working for there example,  they need to update the documents,

Answer (score 1):

Simple way with static IV (initialisation vector):

```
esn = m.constants.deviceSerialID

Function encrypt(args as Object) as String
    iv = "f6a42a2960d374b82d7b333814cbaf8c"
    cipher = CreateObject("roEVPCipher")
    cipher.setup(true, "aes-256-cbc", args.key, iv, 1)

    ba = CreateObject("roByteArray")
    ba.FromAsciiString(args.data)
    result = cipher.process(ba)

    return result.ToBase64String()
End Function


encryptedString = encrypt({
    key: "<symmetrical-secret-key>"
    data: esn
})
```

The IV is just a random hex string. In this example you would need to have the same IV and secret key to decrypt the message back.
The problem here is that static IVs mean we are less secure than we could be. To make this more secure you could make the IV non-static.

```
esn = m.constants.deviceSerialID

Function generateHexString(length As Integer) As String
    hexChars = "0123456789abcdef"
    hexString = ""

    For i = 1 to length
        hexString = hexString + hexChars.Mid(Rnd(length / 2) - 1, 1)
    End for

    Return hexString
End Function

Function encrypt(args as Object) as String
    iv = generateHexString(32)
    cipher = CreateObject("roEVPCipher")
    cipher.setup(true, "aes-256-cbc", args.key, iv, 1)

    ba = CreateObject("roByteArray")
    ba.FromAsciiString(args.data)
    result = cipher.process(ba)

    ' Append the IV to the front of the message
    return iv + result.ToBase64String()
End Function


encryptedString = encrypt({
    key: "<symmetrical-secret-key>"
    data: esn
})
```

Now the IV changes each time you encrypt, much safer. When you come to decrypt the message you know the IV is the first 32 characters so you remove that and use it as the IV to decrypt.

Comment: Prepending the key to your message is hardly what I'd call "secure" lol.

"Hey guys check out the shiny new safe I bought for added security. I've taped the key to the door."